# Any way to create new entry using certain entry type?

Tags: entry

I'm thinking this isn't possible but would be nice if it were?

Just wondering if you have loads of different entry types for a section then it would be nice if there was a way of creating a new entry with a certain entry type *instead* of having to go to create a new entry and *then* select the entry type.

Would be slightly less confusing for clients and would stop some errors in that they would hopefully always get the right entry type instead of typing into the first entry type that shows up.

Comment: Thinking this is more of a feature request for http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/, no?

Comment: You can select the default entry type by moving it to the top of the list, but you want more, right?

Comment: Hi Brad. Okay will add it over there. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something that might already allow this to be done in the CP. Carl, yes a little more than that in that when you go to Entries and click on New if it had a drop-down arrow to allow you to choose the entry type there and then you were taken into a brand new entry with that entry type chosen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about from the control panel?

If that's the case, then the answer is no.

But it sounds like you're asking for a way to maybe set a default entry type?

Regardless, this sounds more like a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com).

Comment: There's already a feature request that would make this possible, I guess: [Raise an event before entry is edited/loaded in CP](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7494886-raise-an-event-before-entry-is-edited-loaded-in-cp). This plus an additional hook to modify the "New Entry" dropdown.

Comment: Feature request added - http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8089776-ability-to-choose-entry-type-when-choosing-to-crea Thanks all.